# Como fazer estas requisições SQL?

Tags: sql

Estou desenvolvendo um portal imobiliário mas como é a primeira vez que faço um, não sei exatamente como funciona a lógica para se chegar ao resultado desejado. Depois de traçar um caminho, eu ainda terei que transformar isso em requisições **SQL**.

Conforme pode ser observado na imagem, eu tenho variantes para `TIPO`, para `DORMITORIOS`, para `AREA`, para `VAGAS`, para `VALOR`, para `BAIRROS`, para `CODIGO`.

Não busca exatamente respostas prontas, busco ideias de como realizar esta tarefa e fico aberto a incrementar informações conforme as dúvidas encontradas.

Coisas que eu já sei:

- Ao digitar um `CODIGO` todos os outros campos serão desconsiderados ...
- Acho que posso começar a filtrar por `VALOR`, `AREA` ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece que TIPO, DORMITORIOS, AREA, VAGAS, VALOR e BAIRROS são os filtros e CODIGO seria um determinado anúncio. Se CODIGO for informado, desconsidere os filtros. Creio que os filtros são opcionais, então cada campo pode assumir um valor *default* para o caso de não ser informado e quando informado você usa o valor na QUERY.

Answer (score 4):

Não há muito segredo sobre como deve ser feito, a regra de negócio da sua tela geralmente é:

**SE** código for informado, deve-se ignorar os outros campos, então, `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE codigo = 'codigo'`, caso contrario, toda vez que um campo vier com dados, você adiciona no seu `WHERE` um `AND` a mais, ex:

- **com tipo de dormitorio**:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE tipo_de_dormitorio = 'tipoDeDormitorio'
  ```
- **com tipo de dormitorio e números de dormitórios**:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM imovel 
      WHERE tipo_de_dormitorio = 'tipoDeDormitorio' 
      AND numero_de_dormitorios = numeroDeDormitorios
  ```
- **com tipo de dormitorio, números de dormitórios e quantidade de vagas**:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM imovel
      WHERE tipo_de_dormitorio = 'tipoDeDormitorio' 
      AND numero_de_dormitorios = numeroDeDormitorios 
      AND numero_de_vagas = numeroDeVagas
  ```

Isso é basicamente falando, depois que você colocar normalização no seu banco, só precisará colocar os `JOIN` nos lugares certos.